# Is a partition necessary when using RAID?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, software-raid, raid1

I have configured raid1 on two of my disks. I am not using a partition, because I want to use the entire disk. Is this correct?

The command `lsblk` produces the following output for my disks:

```
sdc       8:32   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─md4     9:4    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /home
sdd       8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk  
└─md4     9:4    0   1.8T  0 raid1 /home
```

Answer (score 3):

Not using a partition is totally fine. The only struggle that can appear is, if you're exchanging a disk with a different vendor and your new disk is a few blocks smaller.

Comment: You have that with partitions too, if they max out the space on disk.

Comment: If your partition max out definitely, but thats why you just make it a little smaller as the actual disk.

Comment: If I would change out one of the disks and the new disk isn't the same size, is it sufficient to place a partition on the new disk to match the size of the other?

Comment: Yes, if it is bigger. You can also use the complete disk and if all disks are exchanged to the new, bigger size you can grow you md to the new array size.